# Make a ErrorMessage desappear using Formik and Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, formik, yup

I would like to inquire if it's possible to make an ErrorMessage component disappear after a certain period of time. I've been attempting to achieve this using setTimeout, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Thank you for your assistance!

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    inputField: Yup.string().required('Provide a search term.')
})

function Hero() {
    const [errorVisible, setErrorVisible] = useState(true);

    const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        // Simulate API call
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Show the error message
            setErrorVisible(true);

            setTimeout(() => {
                setSubmitting(false);

                // Hide the error message after 3 seconds
                setErrorVisible(false);
            }, 3000);

        }, 3000);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <section className='hero hero__background' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${background})` }}>
                <div className='container-u d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100'>
                    <div className='hero__info'>

                        <h2 className='text-white'>Learn Something New</h2>
                        <p className='text-white'>All courses at $15</p>
                        <Formik
                            initialValues={{ inputField: '' }}
                            validationSchema={validationSchema}
                            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                        >
                            {({ isSubmitting }) => (

                                <Form className='hero__form'>


                                    <Field type="text" name="inputField" className="hero__input" />
                                    {errorVisible && <ErrorMessage name='inputField' component="div" className='text-white text-uppercase fw-bold' /> }
                                    <button style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${search})` }} className='hero__button' type='submit' />

                                </Form>
                            )}
                        </Formik>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try looking into using `useffect` . The initial state of `errorVisible` is set to true so the error message will continue to be true till a re-render happens to update the state based on whatever logic you have to false. You need to make a re-render happen in-order to see your desired out come. Also you have a `setTimeout` in a `setTimeout` and they both have the same number of millisecs.

Answer (score 0):

This one was worked for me. I used this common Error Component for showing errors in UI.

```
const ErrorMessage: FC<IErrorMessageProps> = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <Field name={name}>
      {({ form }: FormikValues) => {
        const error = getIn(form.errors, name);
        const touch = getIn(form.touched, name);
        return (
          <Typography color={'error'} variant="caption">
            {touch && error ? error : null}
          </Typography>
        );
      }}
    </Field>
  );
};
```

To update the internal state of Formik, however, you must use the **values** and **handleChange** props. Then, only Formik was aware of the existence or absence of error. Here how its look like,

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{ inputField: '' }}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit} 
>
        {({ isSubmitting, values, handleChange }) => (
          <Form className="hero__form">
            <Field type="text" name="inputField" className="hero__input" value={values.inputField} onChange={handleChange} />
              <ErrorMessage name="inputField" />
            <button
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${search})` }}
              className="hero__button"
              type="submit"
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

Now, Formik updates the field's values internally whenever it changes. Therefore, the error component only appears if any Yup validation fails and does not indicate that no errors were found. I hope this will help you...